# How do I specifiy the return type for an array of pointers to void?

Tags: c

I want to return an array of pointers to `void`. How do I specify this in the function prototype?

```
int*[] func();
```

Comment: You cannot return arrays in C. You could try returning a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions cannot return array types.  You can either return a pointer to the first element of the array (type `void **`), or you can return a pointer to the whole array (type `void (*)[N]`).  Note that the address value is the same either way (the address of the first element of the array is also the address of the array), it's just a difference in types.

To return a pointer to a SIZE-element array of pointer to `void`, the function signature would be

```
void *(*func())[SIZE]
```

which breaks down as

```
        func             --  func
        func()           --  is a function
       *func()           --  returning a pointer
      (*func())[SIZE]    --  to a SIZE-element array
     *(*func())[SIZE]    --  of pointer
void *(*func())[SIZE]    --  to void.
```

Remember that postfix operators such as `[]` and `()` have higher precedence than unary operators such as `*`, so `*a[]` is an array of pointer and `(*a)[]` is a pointer to an array.

For C89 and earlier, SIZE must be a compile-time constant expression.  For C99 you can use a variable expression.

Whatever you do, **don't** try to return a pointer to an array that's local to the function, such as

```
void *(*func())[SIZE]
{
  void *foo[SIZE];
  ...
  return &foo;
}
```

or

```
void **func()
{
  void *foo[SIZE];
  ...
  return foo;
}
```

Once the function exits, `foo` ceases to exist, and the pointer value returned no longer points anywhere meaningful.  You're either going to have to declare the array as `static` in your function, or you're going to have to dynamically allocate it:

```
void *(*func())[SIZE]
{
  void *(*foo)[SIZE] = malloc(sizeof *foo);
  ...
  return foo;
}
```

or

```
void **func()
{
  void **foo = malloc(sizeof *foo * SIZE);
  ...
  return foo;
}
```

Comment: This helped me really to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

As other people stated you can't really do this because arrays will degrade to pointers.  the standard way to do this is to return a struct

```
struct array {
    void* ptrs[5];
}
```

then your procedure would be declared like

```
struct array foo() {...}
```

Comment: This is far from the "standard" way. Many object to returning such a large object by value rather than by pointer.

Comment: True, there is a copy overhead to returning a large array, so there is a tradeoff between a large copy and managing ownership of a heap allocated object.  But its a tradeoff.  So if all you want to do is pass small arrays by value it will be pretty efficient because copying values on the stack will have good cache locality.  If it is large then the overhead of a system call may be worth it.

Comment: Apart from performance issues, there's the semantic problem because a struct can only contain a *fixed-size* array.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
void **function(int c)
{
    void **arrayOfVoidStars = (void **)malloc(c*sizeof(void *));
    /* fill the array */
    return arrayOfVoidStars;
}
```

Comment: Many people (me included) consider it bad practice to cast the return value of `malloc` in C, and to use `sizeof(type)` as the argument. I prefer `type *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` because it only repeats the typename once. If I change it later, I only need to modify the code in one place.

Comment: @Chris: Or, in this case, `malloc(COUNT * sizeof *p)`.

Comment: @Keith - Of course, sorry. I wrote that from my phone, so I didn't look back at the context to check.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: I like the idea of `sizeof(*p)`. About the casting though, I must admit that is a C++ thing. In C++ you can't assign the `void *` that is returned by `malloc` to any `type *`s. About changing it later, it's not such a big deal, it's the same line and if you miss changing it, you get a compile error so you won't risk any mistakes.

Comment: @Shabaz - It's not always in the same line. Sometimes you use `realloc`. And if you're using C++, it's better to use `new` anyway. I think it's a bad idea to try to write code that compiles in both C and C++ compilers.

Comment: @Django Did you get the answer to your question?